# find the derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus

Find $f'(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the integral from ${\sqrt{x}}$ to $x$ of $e^x-e^{t^2} dt$

Is there an easy way to do this using the fundamental theorem of calculus because if I try to ingretate w.r.t $t$ then $e^{t^2}$ is a bit of a problem.

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/derivative-of-integral

Comment: Perhaps write $\int_{\sqrt x}^x$ as $\int_0^x-\int_0^{\sqrt x}$? For the second integral, let $u=\sqrt x$ and remember that $\frac d{dx} f(u)=f'(u) u'$.

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987915/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-and-second-derivative)

Comment: @columbus8myhw can you explain a bit more please? I usually just find antiderivitives and sub in the limits

Comment: @columbus8myhw Doesn't quite work that way. You still need to evaluate $\int e^{t^2}\,dt$ without using FTC, which doesn't yield a closed form.

Comment: @user108605 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @Marc I'm fairly certain that you don't need to evaluate it! You just need to know that an antiderivative _exists_ (elementary or not), and then you can use the FTC—specifically, $\frac d{dx} \int_0^xf(t)dt=f(x)$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I was under the impression that you are trying to symbolically integrate the function. In any case, when you do apply the FTC, you'll find out that you don't really need to integrate $\sqrt x$ anyway as it has a zero coefficient. Some care is, however, necessary, since the integrand is a function of $x$ as well as $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), which is a formula derived from FTC:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt x}^x(e^x-e^{t^2})dt&=(e^x-e^{x^2})-(e^x-e^x)(\sqrt x)^\prime+\int_{\sqrt x}^x e^x dt \\&= (e^x-e^{x^2})+e^x(x-\sqrt x)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\left(e^x-e^{t^2}\right)dt=e^x(x-\sqrt{x})-\int_0^{x}e^{t^2}dt+\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}e^{t^2}dt$, so

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\left(e^x-e^{t^2}\right)dt=e^{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)+e^x(x-\sqrt{x})-e^{x^2}+e^{x}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

$\hspace{.45 in}=e^x(1+x-\sqrt{x})-e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is.  Assuming no pathological situations, the derivative of a definite integral is the difference of the integrand evaluated at the two endpoints.
So $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_\sqrt{x}^x \left( e^x - e^{t^2} \right) dt = 
\left. 
e^x - \right) dt = 
\left. \left( e^x - e^{t^2} \right)
\right|_{t=\sqrt{x}}^{t=x} = e^x - e^{x^2}
$$

Comment: Incorrect. Your answer assumes that the integrand is not a function of $x$, but in fact it is here. You need to add the term $\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \partial ((e^x-e^{t^2})/\partial x) dt$.